# possible to make Apache listen to ip range?

Tags: ipv6, apache-2.4

Is it possible to make apache webserver listen to a ip range?
for example using:

```
listen 192.168.0.*:80
```

or

```
listen 192.168.0.1/5:80
```

(these examples are for IPv4 but i need it for IPv6 range.)

Comment: it's not about adding to network interface. but selecting ip's for apache to listen to.

Comment: Tell it to listen on `[::]:80`, then it will listen on all IPs assigned to the host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The only options are to either specify each address/port combination, like so:

```
Listen 192.168.0.1:80
```

or one port on all available interfaces, like so:

```
Listen 80
```

Comment: I think i'll go with a port listen than. specifying 65k ip addresses is not my cup of thee.   
thanks

Comment: ...Wow. I quite see your point, there!

Answer (score 0):

Okey the way i wanted is not possible.
but.

```
Listen 80
```

and

```
<VirtualHost [2001:1FF8:4310:A005:0010::1]:80>
```

combined deliver sort of the same result.

although i would like to exclude some ip addresses for other services.
but they are now diverted to 000-default